# How to overcome Error#2146233079: Automation error?

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, com-interop, com+

We have a .NET 3.5 component consumed by VB component through COM+ service. We are following the below steps to register the dll and

1. Executed Regasm.exe /tlb and Regasm.exe /tlb /codebase for the main dll and its dependent dll.
2. Registered VB component dll which consumes .NET dll in COM+.
3. Registered the dotnet dlls of SEAC using step 1.
4. IISRESET

We have 3 servers with identical setup. Those are Dev Server, Test Server, stage Server. It is working fine in dev and Test server and it is giving the following exception in the stage server.

```
Error#2146233079: Automation error
```

We have done the following things in order to resolve the issue. But no luck.

1. Taken a  the  all the dot net and vb dlls for app from the dev server and we deployed in to the Stage server with the process we following to deploy any other dll in dev but we are facing the same issue .
2. same process repeated by taking the Test server. But still facing the same issue
3. Checked in  the registries to confirm the availability of for .net framework 2.0,3.5(only thing we can think here is whether the frameworks are properly installed or not). Seems to be they are installed properly
4. Restarted the Stage server once so that all the old  registry entries are wiped out and then we freshly registered the dlls.Still no luck
5. Make a .Net 3.5 exe and run it in 217 server to check the .Net 3.5  is properly installed or not. It seems to be it is installed perfectly.

Please help to overcome this issue.

Comment: Is there a Stack Trace?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling: Unfortunately NO:(

Comment: Anything in the event log? Also, is the COM+ service running as the same impersonation user on test and staging?

Comment: Also, if you aren't doing it already, put a `try`...`catch` in your constructor, and log any exceptions

Comment: It is -2146233079.  Which is a managed exception code, 0x80131509, it means InvalidOperationException.  You will need to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I have cracked this issue.

**Root cause and resolution:**
One of the .NET dll is missed in that machine. Generally development and testing we have installed .NET framework and Visual studio. However in stage and production we have installed only .NET framework and not entire Visualstudio suite. We are suspecting that is the reason. We have registered that component in GAC of the stage and production machines and issue got resolved.

**How did I crack**
(1) We have identified at what action the issue occurring and placed logs on the interface where VB component creating instance of .NET component and VB calling .NET component functions and recognized which function it is giving error

(2) In that function we have placed try catch and logged the exception message in some external file.

(3) Through exception message we have identified the specific dll has been missed